# Algorithms for Fixing Sudokus

Tags: computational-complexity, game-theory, combinatorial-optimization, sudoku

Suppose someone got stuck solving a Sudoku and asks you to figure out, what went wrong. Unfortunately that person only sends you a copy of the instance, where you neither see which of the numbers constituted to the initial set of numbers, nor do you get any information about the order in which the other numbers have been entered.
Note that some of the fields may not have entries because the Sudoku was not finished when the contradiction to the filling rules was realized.

> **Question:**
>   what is the complexity of detecting the minimal set of entries, whose removal would restore the solvability of the Sudoku instance?

Edit:
as a clarification in response to Brendan McKay's comment I would ask for the complexity of fixing Sudokus generalized to boards of size $n^2\times n^2$, where each of $n^2$ symbols must appear exactly once in each row, in each column and in each of the $n\times n$-sized subsquares whose disjoint union covers the board's cells; this kind of generalization is depicted in the wikipedia article on [generalized games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_game)

Comment: It takes constant time, because there are only finitely many possibilities. Perhaps you meant to consider some generalization of Sudoku to arbitrarily large boards, but there is more than one way to generalise and you need to specify which you want.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay good point; I simply overlooked that. I now edited the question, so that possible answers will be more interesting.

Comment: Is it known whether solving a Sudoku is in NP?  If so, then this problem is likely of the same complexity.  I imagine this is equivalent to finding a maximal set of consistent constraints in a CSP system.  Gerhard "Coffee: Foundational To My Consistency" Paseman, 2018.03.17.

Comment: In general solving n x n Sudoku is NP-complete. If you are promised there's a unique solution (as is often the case with actual Sudoku puzzles) it is in UP, but still hard for NP under randomized poly-time reductions.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow but my question is not aimed at actually solving a Sudoku, but rather at removing entries of a partially filled Sudoku to restore solvability; is that problem also of the same complexity?

Comment: @GerhardPaseman even if the problem of solving a Sudoku is in NP, verifying a solution is in P, and the question is, whether my problem is more related to finding a solution or to verifying a solution.

Comment: Yes, but you can ask a similar kind of question for many NP-complete problems, and in all examples I know of, the analogous questions for other NP-complete problems remain NP-complete. So, I agree with Gerhard Paseman, your probably is very likely NP-complete. (More technically, it is an NP-optimization problem that is NP-hard.)

Answer (score 1):

An algorithm that finds a minimal set of entries whose removal restores the solvability of a Sudoku puzzle has essentially the same complexity as one that solves the puzzle. Just repeat trying each possible single entry in turn, keep those for which the algorithm returns the empty set.